# Why is there a problem with the creation of binary trees?

Tags: c

the code is in order to create a binary tree stored in a sequential structure,
and to be able to traverse the binary tree in a previous order. However ,
when I create the binary tree, it can't output.
Why is there a problem with the creation of binary trees?
Is the struct has something wrong?  please tell me how can I solve this problem?
I will be appreciate you for what you have done.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
}Tree;
typedef struct bit
{
    Tree *a[100];
    int length;
}Bitree;

typedef struct Stack
{
    Tree *sq[1000];
    int top;
}stack;

int empty(stack s)
{
    return s.top==-1;
}

void push(stack *s,Tree *p)
{
    s->sq[++s->top]=p;
}

void pop(stack *s)
{
    if(s->top!=-1)
    {
        s->top--;
    }
}
//return the top element


Tree *top(stack s)
{
    if(s.top!=-1)
        return s.sq[s.top];
}
Bitree *create(Bitree *tree1,int n)
{
    int x;
    tree1->a[0]->data=1;
    printf("%d ",tree1->a[0]->data);
    tree1->length=0;
    printf("请输入根节点\n");
    scanf("%d ",&x);
    tree1->a[1]->data=x;
    tree1->length++;
    for(int i=2;i<=n;i++)
    {
        if(i%2==0)
        {
            printf("please input left binary tree\n");
            scanf("%d ",&x);
            tree1->a[i]->data=x;
            tree1->a[i/2]->left=tree1->a[i];
            tree1->length++;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("please input right binary tree\n");
            scanf("%d ",&x);
            tree1->a[i]->data=x;
            tree1->a[i/2]->right=tree1->a[i];
            tree1->length++;
        }
    }
    return tree1;
}
void preorder1(Bitree *t)
{
    stack s;
    s.top=-1;
    if(t->a[1]!=NULL) {
        push(&s,t->a[1]);
    }
    while(!empty(s))
    {
        Tree *x=top(s);
        pop(&s);
        printf("%d ",x->data);
        if(x->right!=NULL)
            push(&s,x->right);
        if(x->left!=NULL)
            push(&s,x->left);
    }
}
int main()
{

    int n;
    Bitree *t1;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    t1=create(t1,n);
    preorder1(t1);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running your code line by line in a debugger while monitoring the values of all variables, in order to determine at which point your program stops behaving as intended? If you did not try this, then you may want to read this: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/12149471)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with exact input, intended output and actual output. The statement "it can't output" is not a sufficient description of the error. Does the program not output anything although you expect it to? Or is it outputting what seems to be random characters?

Comment: `printf("请输入根节点\n");` risks undefined behavior as the encoding may contain a byte of `%` leading to trouble.  Better to use `printf("%s", "请输入根节点\n");` or `fwprint()`.

Comment: `s->sq[++s->top]=p` is undefined behavior. If an object is modified, it's only permitted to access its value for the purpose of modification. `s->sq` violates that.

Comment: No, @sj95126, that applies only to *scalar* objects.  Neither `*s` not `s->sq` is a scalar.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: `s` is the scalar object. It's being modified (`++s`) and accessed (dereferenced as `s->sq`).

Comment: @sj95126, `++s` is not evaluated in that expression.  The `->` has higher precedence than prefix `++`, so the expression is equivalent to `s->sq[++(s->top)]=p`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: sorry, my mistake. It's *postfix* increment that has the same precedence as `->`

Answer (score 1):

First problem I see , you forgot to allocate your `Bitree` and the `a` structure in it . try this :

```
int main()
{

int n;
Bitree *t1 = (Bitree*) malloc(sizeof(Bitree));
int i = 0 ; 
for(i ; i < 100 ; i++)
        t1->a[i] = (Tree*) malloc(sizeof(Tree)); 
scanf("%d",&n);
t1=create(t1,n);
preorder1(t1);
for(i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++)
        free(t1->a[i]); 
free(t1); 
}
```

Comment: thanks your answer. but your answer may be  wrong. First,  t1 , t1->a[i] have  space and  shouldn't be malloc . Second ,  I use your main function to test ,it still has something wrong.

Comment: @waggghhh oh , it has already been allocated then ? My bad then , I thought you had an issue with the segfault . 
So , your issue is more with the algorithm used , I guess ?

Comment: yes, my issue is about why the algorithm used  in the create binary tree  in a sequential structure. when I use the create function , it even can't printf my tips and can't create t1 correctly.

Comment: @waggghhh, the code presented in the question *does not* allocate space for `main()`'s variable `t1` to point to, neither in `main` nor in `create`, yet `create()` assumes that the pointer it receives as its argument is valid.  That is definitely an error, just as this answer points out.  If `t1` did have sufficient space allocated then that would include storage for the 100 elements of `t1->a`, but that's a separate matter.

Comment: @waggghhh are you sure you correctly allocated your structures like I did ? 
Because I definitely have your printfs and scanfs working on my setup. 
I didn't verify if your preorder function is correct on the algorithmic aspect yet , but if you don't have anything printed out , it's surely because your structures are not allocated.

Comment: @waggghhh, Also, the the elements of `t1->a` would exist if `*t1` in fact existed, but these are *pointers* that, just like `t1` in actuality, don't point to anything unless you assign valid pointer values to them.  So this answer is exactly right about both of those issues (+1).  It is possible to resolve those issues without dynamic memory allocation, but these together constitute a large part of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Major issues with this program include:**

- Dereferencing the indeterminate initial value of `main()`'s pointer `t1`, as [@AsmineBensalem observed first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69696657/2402272).

  The signature of function `create()` suggests that there may have been some confusion about how space was supposed to be allocated -- `create()` receives a pointer to a `Bitree`, but also returns one.  If that function were expected to allocate the space, then it would not need to receive a pointer to existing space, but given that it in fact relies on the caller to provide a valid `Bitree *`, there seems little point in it echoing that same pointer value back to the caller.

  For the record, given `create()` as presently written, I would write `main()` like so (without `malloc()`):

  ```
  int main(void) {
      int n;
      Bitree t1 = { .length = 0 };  // not a pointer; with initializer

      scanf("%d", &n);
      create(&t1, n);
      preorder1(&t1);
  }
  ```

  Declaring `t1` as a `Bitree` instead of a `Bitree *` provides storage for the whole `Bitree` instead of just for a pointer to one.  See below for more about the initializer.
- Dereferencing the values of elements of `t1->a` when these (pointer) values are indeterminate, also as @AsmineBensalem observed first.  This is essentially the same as the previous issue, and its recurrence suggests that you do not understand that declaring a pointer gets you *only* a pointer, not an object for it to point to.  Since you seem to be trying to avoid dynamic allocation, you could start a solution to this by changing the definition of type `Bitree` to contain an array of the needed `Tree` objects instead of pointers to such objects:

  ```
  typedef struct bit {
      Tree a[100];  // array of Tree, not of Tree *
      int length;
  } Bitree;
  ```

  That will require several additional changes elsewhere in the code, but these are straightforward.
- Failing to initialize the `left` and `right` pointers of nodes that have fewer than two children.  Your `preorder()` function assumes that these will be `NULL` where a node has no child in the specified direction, but `create()` does not ensure that.

  You could, however, get that automatically by changing the definition of `Bitree` as described in the previous point, *and* ensuring that your `Bitree` object is declared with an initializer, as shown in the first point above.  In that case, you don't have to explicitly initialize all the pointers to get null initial values for them, but you do need to provide an initializer for at least some part of the `Bitree`.

  Alternatively, you could just have `create()` explicitly assign `NULL` to the child pointers of each node it initializes.

**Additional issues include:**

- Function `create()`'s `scanf()` formats cause misleading behavior.  This code appears three times:

  > ```
  >     scanf("%d ",&x);
  > ```

  The trailing whitespace in the format matches any amount of whitespace, so `scanf` has to match it by continuing to read whitespace until it sees non-witespace.  The practical effect is that the user has to input the value for each non-root node *before* the prompt for that node is printed, and they need to input an extra value or some kind of trailing junk in order to complete the input stage.  Just remove the space at the end of each of these formats:

  ```
      scanf("%d", &x);
  ```
- Function `top()` is declared to return a `Tree *`, but when the `stack` passed to it is empty, it terminates without returning anything.
- Functions `top()` and `empty()` each receive a `stack` as an argument, *by value*.  Although this is not inherently wrong, it does, in principle, involve making a copy of the caller's argument at every call.  `stack` is a pretty big structure, so this is undesirable.
- It is surprising that `pop()` pops an element from the stack without returning it.  You work with that by first retrieving the top element with `top()` and then `pop()`ping it, but it would be much more conventional to have `pop()` both pop an element off the stack and return that element.
- It is surprising and unnecessary that `create()` does not use the tree node at index 0.  (I discount entering a dummy value into it, since that's purposeless when you don't mean for that value to be accessed elsewhere.)